# Как выводить широту элемента на экран при изменении ширины элемента сплиттером?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Как выводить широту элемента на экран с использованием синтаксиса самого C# даже при изменении ширины элемента сплиттером? То есть перетащив сплиттер в сторону - вместо чисел в выделенных красных квадратах отображалась бы ширина каждого прямоугольника в котором находится число.
[image]

```xml
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="2*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid Grid.ColumnSpan="3">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Grid.Row="2">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <GridSplitter Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" 
                      ShowsPreview="False" Width="3"
                      HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                      VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />
            <Canvas Grid.Column="0" 
                    Background="GreenYellow">
                <TextBlock Text="3"/>
            </Canvas>
            <Canvas Grid.Column="2" 
                    Background="Green">
                <TextBlock Text="4"/>
            </Canvas>
        </Grid>
        <GridSplitter Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" 
                      ShowsPreview="False" Width="3"
                      HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                      VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />
        <Canvas Grid.Column="0" Background="NavajoWhite" Grid.Row="0">
            <TextBlock Text="1"/>
        </Canvas>
        <Canvas Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0" Background="Purple">
            <TextBlock Text="2"/>
        </Canvas>
    </Grid>
    <GridSplitter Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" 
                  ShowsPreview="False" Width="3"
                  HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                  VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />
    <Canvas Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Background="Blue">
        <TextBlock Text="5"/>
    </Canvas>
    <Canvas Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" Background="Yellow">
        <TextBlock Text="6"/>
    </Canvas>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Попробуйте так `<TextBlock Text="{Binding ActualWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"/>` или так `<TextBlock Text="{Binding ActualWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Canvas}}"/>`

Comment: Кстати, непонятно, зачем вам здесь канвасы, если можно их убрать и задать цвет фона самому текстблоку.

Comment: @aepot ,Спасибо за ответ выше, а про канвас... его ещё нужно будет превратить в кнопку, которую можно было бы растягивать(ведь вправо их должно быть штук 20-30 да и вниз в пару раз больше и вдобавок ещё ScrollBar вертикальный и горизонтальный :) ) и при нажатии она меняла бы цвет. В общем кошкин дом) В вопросе разукрашены для видимости разделения

Comment: Сработало? Что именно сработало?

Comment: @aepot Со вторым вариантом. А как обратиться к Text элемента в коде C#?

Comment: В данном конкретном случае без изменений привязки никак, но я попробую набросать пример с привязкой данных.

Comment: Чет мне кажется вы не в том направление двигаетесь... Судя по первому вашему вопросу, piano roll из fl studio, там ведь сетка статична, а на нее драг ен дропом кидаются прямоугольники, которые возможно растянуть за края (`GridRowSpan` и `GridColumnSpan`). Зачем вам тут вдруг `GridSplitter` понадобился?

Comment: Давайте так, я дал ответ. Разберитесь, что там и как, а про C# задайте отдельный вопрос. Или поищите ответ, как получить `ActualWidth` в C# с помощью привязки `Binding`.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ не совсем понимаю про какой драг энд дроп вы говорите и про то как растягивать края GridRowSpan в уже скомпилированном окне тоже...
С помощью грид сплиттера была идея растягивать прямоугольник, от ширины которого напрямую зависела бы длительность воспроизводимого звука(хоть он и затухаящая синусоида)

Comment: Ну посмотрите как работает для начала та программа, которую вы пытаетесь скопировать, увидите там сетку, которую нельзя как либо изменить, она статично (лишь масштаб можно), на этой сетке можно "нарисовать" прямоугольник, нажав карандашом в нужную ячейку, а сами прямоугольники вы можете передвинуть, зажав мышью на них и потянуть куда надо (Dran&Drop зовется). Растягивание там работает не по размеру объекта, а сколько клеток в сетке он занимает (в WPF это `Grid*Span` свойства). А вы сейчас коверкаете сетку зачем то...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так

```xml
<TextBlock Text="{Binding ActualWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"/>
```

или так

```xml
<TextBlock Text="{Binding ActualWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Canvas}}"/>
```

Лучше не делайте дерево гридов, лучше сделайте один старший грид, отвечающий за высоту вложенных гридов, и внутри 3 грида со сплиттерами. Это позволит избежать большой вложенности, если надо много таких строчек. Грубо говоря, вместо `<Grid>1<Grid>2<Grid>3</Grid></Grid></Grid>` сделайте `<Grid><Grid>1</Grid><Grid>2</Grid><Grid>3</Grid></Grid>`. Один лишний грид, но читаемость разметки будет значительно лучше.

У меня вот так получилось. Вместо `Canvas` использовал `Border`, так как первый предназначен для всяких фигур, и он не очень подходит под текущую ситуацию по поведению.

```xml
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type GridSplitter}">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
            <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
            <Setter Property="ShowsPreview" Value="False"/>
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="3"/>
        </Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
            <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding ActualWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Border}, StringFormat=F2}"/>
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="5"/>
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="20"/>
            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
            <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        </Style>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <GridSplitter Grid.Column="1"/>
        <Border Background="NavajoWhite">
            <TextBlock/>
        </Border>
        <Border Grid.Column="2" Background="Purple">
            <TextBlock/>
        </Border>
    </Grid>
    <Grid Grid.Row="1">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <GridSplitter Grid.Column="1"/>
        <Border Background="Blue">
            <TextBlock/>
        </Border>
        <Border Grid.Column="2" Background="Yellow">
            <TextBlock/>
        </Border>
    </Grid>
    <Grid Grid.Row="2">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <GridSplitter Grid.Column="1"/>
        <Border Background="GreenYellow">
            <TextBlock/>
        </Border>
        <Border Grid.Column="2" Background="Green">
            <TextBlock/>
        </Border>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]